# Extending an HTML Element

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I am using ES5 to make a custom web component that extends `HTMLAnchorElement`. Since web components only work in ES6 and up I have included the ES5 polyfill located [here.](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#user-content-custom-elements-es5-adapterjs)

Making a web component that extends `HTMLElement` and then using its tag on the page works fine. But extending any element other than `HTMLElement` does not seem to work.

I am using the latest version of Google Chrome to test this.

Below is my code for the element that is extending `HTMLAnchorElement`.

```
function CustomAnchor() {
    HTMLAnchorElement.call(this);
}

CustomAnchor.prototype.connectedCallback = function () {
    console.log('anchor added to dom');

    this.addEventListener('click', 
        function(e) {
            console.log('test');
            e.preventDefault();
            var result = confirm('Confirmed!');
        }
    );
};

window.customElements.define('custom-anchor', CustomAnchor, {extends: 'a'});
```

And here is the code that creates the element and adds it to the DOM:

```
var el1 = document.createElement("a")
el1.setAttribute("is", "custom-anchor")
el1.setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.com/")
el1.text = "Go to Google"
document.body.appendChild(el1)
```

And here is what shows up in the DOM, which looks correct:

```
<a is="custom-anchor" href="http://www.google.com/">Go to Google</a>
```

No errors are showing up in the console but when the element is appended to the DOM the `connectedCallback` is never fired.

The link works just like a normal anchor link as if it had never been extended.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: None of this is correct. 1st, you cannot extend specific elements, just HTMLElement. 2nd, why are you using ES 5 with the adapter in the latest chrome? Use classes like the spec requires. Use the shim you linked and babel for old browsers. Side note: I have trouble with the connectedCallback firing too early, I usually wrap the contents in a `setTimeout` of 0. See [this](https://github.com/shawnbot/custom-elements#class-definition) for more info.

Comment: @JaredSmith I'm actually using Kotlin which is why I need the ES5 adapter. I'm showing you guys almost exactly what the Kotlin compiler outputted. Lastly, you **can** extend specific elements. It is part of the spec. I suggest you do some reading to bring yourself up to speed.

Comment: @JaredSmith here you go, this is what you need to read: https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/#custom-elements-customized-builtin-example

Comment: I stand corrected. Have a +1. However its not implemented (or if it is it's behind a flag), doing `class Foo extends HTMLButtonElement` throws an illegal constructor error on the call to `super` in Chrome 62. I would also advise against trying to do bleeding-edge browser stuff in a language other than JavaScript unless its a POC: too hard to tell where in the process something went wrong. I can tell you from painful personal experience that the devtools error messages for brand new stuff (e.g. modules, native custom elements) are more opaque than their more well-worn counterparts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried running the example from the link I posted and it appears that you're right. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create new instance of an extended class of custom elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39986046/how-to-create-new-instance-of-an-extended-class-of-custom-elements)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Nov 28, 2017 extending anything besides `HTMLElement` is not supported in any browser. The idea of `<button is="my-button">Click Me</button>` is not supported in Native V1 components.

For more info read the section `Extending native HTML elements` found here: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements

it states:
"*Warning: At time of writing, no browser has implemented customized built-in elements (status). This is unfortunate for accessibility and progressive enhancement. If you think extending native HTML elements is useful, voice your thoughts on Github.*"

**UPDATE 1:**

As of May 28 2018 Chrome 67 supports Customized built-in elements
And Firefox 63 claims full support too.

> Sometime in Sept or Oct 2018 MS started working on their support for Custom Elements and Shadow DOM in Edge. *But there is no indication on when it will be finished.*

Comment: Would you please provide a source for this?

Comment: in my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47510957/how-do-you-decouple-web-components/47521377#47521377 I have provided the source for two simple Web Components.