# Custom HTML tag

Tags: javascript, html, tags, popover

I have the following HTML:

```
<a class="rounded" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover"
data-html="true" data-placement="right" data-title="some data title"
data-content="some data content" href="#" onclick="return false;"
onmouseover="onMouseOver();" onmouseout="onMouseOut();">
    <i class="fas fa-info-circle fa-sm" aria-hidden="true" style="color: var(--tint-color);"></i>
</a>

<script>
  function onMouseOver() { console.log('onMouseOver') }
  function onMouseOut() { console.log('onMouseOut') }
</script>
```

which I repeatedly call with different values of `data-title` and `data-content`. Is there a way to have a **custom tag** such as:

```
<popover data-title="some data title" data-content="some data content"></popover>
```

Is this the best method for achieving this, or is making a CSS class more suitable?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539002/extending-an-html-element

Answer (score 0):

You can't add custom HTML tags, but you can add "id" or "class" to any HTML tag.
For example, instead of:

```
<popover data-title="some data title" data-content="some data content"></popover>
```

Do:

```
<div id="popover" data-title="some data title" data-content="some data content"><div>
```

You can then select your customized div using jQuery:

```
<script>$("#popover").mouseover(function (){ console.log("onMouseOver")});</script>
```

If you need more than one custom item, that must behave in the exact same way, you can then do this:

```
     <div class="popover" data-title="some data title" data-content="some data content"><div>
 <script>$(".popover").mouseover(function (){console.log("onMouseOver")});</script>
```