# Extending `<header>` , `<main>`, `<footer>` and `<aside>` tags

Tags: html

What is correct class to extend `<header>`, `<main>`, `<footer>` and `<aside>` tags. There is no `HTMLHeaderElement`, `HTMLMainElement`, `HTMLFooterElement` and `HTMLAsideElement`

So what is correct way to get behavior

```js
class CustomHeader extends what? <!-- HTMLElement --> {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
class CustomMain extends what? <!-- HTMLElement --> {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
class CustomFooter extends what? <!-- HTMLElement --> {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
class CustomAside extends what? <!-- HTMLElement --> {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
customElements.define('custom-header', CustomHeader, { extends: 'header' })
customElements.define('custom-main', CustomMain, { extends: 'main' })
customElements.define('custom-footer', CustomFooter, { extends: 'footer' })
customElements.define('custom-aside', CustomAside, { extends: 'aside' })
```

```html
<header is="custom-header"></header>
<main is="custom-main"></main>
<footer is="custom-footer"></footer>
<aside is="custom-aside"></aside>
```

- [Extending an HTML Element](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47545187/1318830) is not answering the question

Comment: no framework, trying to find simplest native way using supported browser API https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-is

Comment: My apologies. I should do better research. It's not a feature I'd heard of before, and I jumped to conclusions. Sorry about that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending an HTML Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47539002/extending-an-html-element)

Comment: "As of Nov 28, 2017 extending anything besides HTMLElement is not supported in any browser", "As of May 28 2018 Chrome 67 supports Customized built-in elements And Firefox 63 claims full support too." so NO! we are in 2021

Answer (score 0):

There are currently no global interfaces for `header`, `main`, `aside`, ect. elements so it looks like what you are doing right now is correct. Although, most browsers will force this instance to adhere to the guidelines in the spec for the element you bind the `HTMLElement` object to (i.e. permitted aria rules).  You can check MDN's `DOM Interface` column for element listings if you do want to see if there is a better class available.

| Element Name | DOM Interface |
| --- | --- |
| [`header`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/header) | `HTMLElement` |
| [`main`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main) | `HTMLElement` |
| [`aside`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/aside) | `HTMLElement` |

Comment: so if I set `aria-label` for `extended HTMLElement` it will work as expected?