# how to pass objects in web component javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-component

I want to pass an object as a property to my custom element. Passing this object as an attribute does not work not even after stringifying it. is there a way to do something like this:

```
let data = [
  { name: "Peter", expand: false },
  { name: "Max", expand: false },
  { name: "Lucy", expand: true }
];

<my-dropdown-list  data="${data}"></my-dropdown-list>
```

data is treated as attribute in my component js file. How do i pass data as a property in to my component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Web Components, pass data to and from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50404970/web-components-pass-data-to-and-from)

Comment: thanks. Using getter setter it worked. Just wanted to know if there is any cleaner way to do the same . For example in angular we pass objects using properties in <my-component [data]=data></my-component> . Hence here we are not passing value progmatically but through html.

Comment: @sumit You are *declaring* the data in HTML, Angular (using a fair amount of code) takes part of *passing* the data.. without a Framework you have to do all that yourself.

Comment: yeah i agree @Danny'365CSI'Engelman. So for now i'm okay with passing property as suggested by in the first comment